# vertx 3.5.1 missing classes

Tags: maven, vert.x

I started to look into developing with VertX, and I stumbled into problems with some classes that couldnt be resolved. I am posting a simple example.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


<groupId>demo.rabbit</groupId>
<artifactId>rabbitmq-client</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

java code

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.AsyncResult;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;

public class RabbitMQVerticle extends AbstractVerticle
{
   @Override
   public void start() throws Exception {
       AsyncResult ar;
       JsonObject jo;
   }
 }
```

If I leave it like this, the compiler cannot resolve the AsyncResult and JsonObject imports, and thus cannot resolve both types.

In the external libraries view, those classes appear as part of the io.vertx.core library but the icon next to them indicates that they are missing from the library.
[image: external library view]

If I replace the vertx.core version to 3.5.0 in the pom file everything works great, switch back to 3.5.1 and nothing works again.

It's also my first time using Maven, what am I missing?
Couldn't find any useful information anywhere on the web

Comment: It's mavens problem, not vertx'

Comment: well, my pom is pretty straight forward. one dependency is all i need. What could be the problem?

Comment: I've been using vertx with gradle for 2 years now, and has never problems with upgrades or whatever

Comment: I ended up deleting the whole maven repository cache, which worked. Can't believe I wasted so much time on this!

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned classes are parts of the *core* *Vert.x* library. *Core* blocks never get deleted in mature libraries.

Here down the `AsyncResult` class for example under both versions:

- [`AsyncResult` under *3.5.0* version](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/3.5.0/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/AsyncResult.java)
- [`AsyncResult` under *3.5.1* version](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/3.5.1/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/AsyncResult.java)

Indeed I think even when changing the library version, your project still compiles (using cmd line or using *IntelliJ IDEA*) but you are facing a UI highlight issue with you IDE.

You can try to:

- Re-import all *Maven* modules using the [*Maven Projects Tool Window*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html)
- [Clean the system caches and restart the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Cleaning_System_Cache.html)